# Jenkins error: package javax.mail does not exist import javax.mail.Message;

Tags: java, eclipse, email, jenkins, gradle

In my code I'm running some tests using Appium and SeeTest.Io. 
When I run the code from Eclipse, it works fine and sends the e-mail after the test.

```
package apptest;


import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;

import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Optional;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.experitest.appium.SeeTestClient;


import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;



public class WP_Login extends BaseTest implements GlobalConstants { 
    protected AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = null;
    protected SeeTestClient client;
    protected String ReportURL = System.getenv("ReportURL");
    protected String TestName = System.getenv("testName");

@BeforeMethod
@Parameters("deviceQuery")
public void setUp(@Optional("@os='android'") String deviceQuery) throws Exception{
    init(deviceQuery);
    // Init application / device capabilities
    /*dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "cloud:com.consul.android.smartbeer.staging/com.whirlpool.ted.View.SplashActivity");
    dc.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE, "com.consul.android.smartbeer.staging");
    dc.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, "com.whirlpool.ted.View.SplashActivity");*/
    dc.setCapability("testName", "wp_TED_Login");
    dc.setCapability("deviceQuery",S8+"or"+S7+"or"+S6Edge+"or"+S7Edge);
    //dc.setCapability("deviceQuery",androidnuvem);
    driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL(getProperty("url",cloudProperties) +"/wd/hub"), dc);
    client = new SeeTestClient(driver);

}

@Test
 public void testeLogin() {
      driver.installApp("cloud:com.consul.smartbeer/com.whirlpool.ted.View.SplashActivity");
      client.launch("com.consul.smartbeer/com.whirlpool.ted.View.SplashActivity", false, true);
      try{Thread.sleep(esperandogifinicial);} catch(Exception ignore){}
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='Acesse sua conta']")).click();
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='edEmail']")).sendKeys("tedmonitoramento@gmail.com");
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='edPassword']")).sendKeys("Smart2000");
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='Entrar']")).click();
}

/*@Test
 public void testeLoginQA() {
  driver.installApp("cloud:com.consul.android.smartbeer.staging/com.whirlpool.ted.View.SplashActivity");
  client.launch("com.consul.android.smartbeer.staging/com.whirlpool.ted.View.SplashActivity", false, true);
  try{Thread.sleep(esperandogifinicial);} catch(Exception ignore){}
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='Acesse sua conta']")).click();
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='edEmail']")).sendKeys("tedmonitoramento@gmail.com");
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='edPassword']")).sendKeys("Smart2000");
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='Entrar']")).click();
  try{Thread.sleep(esperandogifinicial+2500);} catch(Exception ignore){}
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='imgCart']")).click();
}*/

@AfterMethod
public void tearDown(ITestResult tr) throws AddressException, MessagingException{
    driver.removeApp("com.consul.android.smartbeer.staging");
    ReportURL = driver.getCapabilities().getCapability("reportUrl").toString();
    TestName = "wp_TED_Login";
    if (driver!=null)
    {
        Email e = new Email();
        e.setMailServerProperties();
        e.createEmailMessage(ReportURL, TestName);
        e.sendEmail();
        if (tr.isSuccess()) 
        {
            client.report("Test has passed", true);

        }
        else {
            client.report("Test has failed", false);
        }
        System.out.println("report URL : " + driver.getCapabilities().getCapability("reportUrl"));
        //System.getenv(driver.getCapabilities().getCapability("reportUrl"));
        System.setProperty(ReportURL, driver.getCapabilities().getCapability("reportUrl").toString());
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

}

***But when I try to run the same code using Jenkins, the tests fails and brings me this result***

> Iniciado pelo usu�rio Lucas Moreira dos Santos Construindo no
>   workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\TED_Login
>
> > git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10 Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
> >     git.exe config remote.origin.url https://lar-whirlpool@bitbucket.org/whirlpooldigital/automated-testing.git
> >
> > ## timeout=10 Fetching upstream changes from https://lar-whirlpool@bitbucket.org/whirlpooldigital/automated-testing.git
> >
> > git.exe --version # timeout=10 using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
> >     git.exe fetch --tags --progress https://lar-whirlpool@bitbucket.org/whirlpooldigital/automated-testing.git
> >     +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
> >     git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
> >     git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10 Checking out Revision
> >     29b14ff325d23e5efb59ed6a24c45b41422e6fa4 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
> >     git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
> >     git.exe checkout -f 29b14ff325d23e5efb59ed6a24c45b41422e6fa4 Commit message: "teste"
> >     git.exe rev-list --no-walk 2cef3325f58cc91f607bccc2aa930d54c46313f4 # timeout=10 [Gradle] - Launching build. [TED_Login] $ cmd.exe /C '""C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\TED_Login\gradlew.bat"'
> >     test --tests apptest.WP_Login.testeLogin && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"
> >     Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 3 stopped Daemons could
> >     not be reused, use --status for details :compileJava NO-SOURCE
> >     :processResources NO-SOURCE :classes UP-TO-DATE
> >     :compileTestJavaC:\Program Files
> >     (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\TED_Login\src\test\java\apptest\Email.java:5:
> >     error: package javax.mail does not exist import javax.mail.Message;
> >                      ^ C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\TED_Login\src\test\java\apptest\Email.java:6:
> >     error: package javax.mail does not exist import
> >     javax.mail.MessagingException;
> >                      ^ C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\TED_Login\src\test\java\apptest\Email.java:7:
> >     error: package javax.mail does not exist import javax.mail.Session;
> >                      ^ C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\TED_Login\src\test\java\apptest\Email.java:8:
> >     error: package javax.mail does not exist import javax.mail.Transport;
> >                      ^ C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\TED_Login\src\test\java\apptest\Email.java:9:
> >     error: package javax.mail.internet does not exist import
> >     javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
> >                               ^ C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\TED_Login\src\test\java\apptest\Email.java:10:
> >     error: package javax.mail.internet does not exist import
> >     javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
> >                               ^ C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\TED_Login\src\test\java\apptest\Email.java:11:
> >     error: package javax.mail.internet does not exist import
> >     javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
> >     FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':compileTestJava'.
>
>   > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 19s 1 actionable task: 1 executed Build step 'Invoke
>   Gradle script' changed build result to FAILURE Build step 'Invoke
>   Gradle script' marked build as failure Finished: FAILURE

My doubt is: should I edit anything in build.gradle inside Eclipse or is there any way to import this JAR's into Jenkins?
Because on Eclipse it works fine

Here is my file build.gradle

```
group 'com.experitest'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://cloud.experitest.com/repo" }
    maven { url "http://repo.experitest.com:8010/Maven2/"}

    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile(group: 'com.experitest', name: 'seetest-appium', version: '10.8')
    compile 'com.experitest:manager-client:1.6'
    compile group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version: '6.9.10'
    compile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
    compile 'com.experitest:repo:1.1'
    compile 'com.experitest:appium-seetest-extension:11.4'
}

test {
    useTestNG()
}
```

Comment: Please show your Gradle build.gradle file, it sounds like you don't have JavaMail on your classpath when compiling through Jenkins. This could indicate you don't have the dependency correctly defined in your gradle file.

Comment: I've inserted it into the question

Comment: There are no JavaMail dependencies in that build file. You need to add the right dependency in your gradle file. Also, did you really intend to put test-dependencies on the normal `compile` scope (instead of the `testCompile` scope)? Unless you're writing a test library, it is unlikely that your test dependencies should be on `compile` scope.

Comment: Thank you! It worked!
About the test-dependencies, I'm using it as it came from experitest.com